# refresh token "error" : "invalid_client" on google app script - new feature upgrade auth

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I am very happy with the new feature [authUpgrade](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts#authUpgrade) but I am getting -  `"error" : "invalid_client"`  when I try to fetch a new refresh token. How can I fix this?
Here is my code:

```
var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("blogger");
var code = UserProperties.getProperties();
var tokenEndpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
var postPayload = {
  "refresh_token" : code.refresh_token,
  "client_id" : code.clientId, // also trying "8774700966@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
  "client_secret" : code.clientSecret,
  "grant_type" : "refresh_token"
};

 var options = {
  "method" : "post",
  "payload" : postPayload
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenEndpoint, options);
```

Thx in advance

Metamorfoself

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in a PHP OAuth client library built to work with Google. Taking a closer look at the request (which was being sent by PHP CURL) there was a lot of mysterious whitespace being added to the client-secret.

```
client-secret='XXXX   '; is not the same as client-secret='XXXX';
```

So a suggestion will be to make sure that this is not happening.

You will get invalid_client even though your credentials are right

Hope this helps someone!